# SQL join 2 tables together

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have a problem with joining 2 tables

Here is my first table with the name "users"

**user_id**     **user_username**     **user_password**     **user_name**
1                   admin                           admin123                   john
3                   test                                test123                         alex

And here is my second table "posts"

**post_id**     **post_content**     **post_userid**
1                   Lorem ipsum..     1
2                   Second post ..     3

---

## I wanna show it like this:

```
post_id | post_content   | post_userid | user_id | user_username | user_password |     user_name
--------|----------------|-------------|---------|---------------|---------------|---------------
1       | Lorem ipsum..  | 1           | 1       | admin         | admin123      | john
2       | Second post .. | 3           | 3       | test          | test123       | alex
```

---

I've allready tried

```
SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON(post_userid = user_id)
```

but that only shows the first post.

Then i tried

```
SELECT * FROM posts FULL OUTER JOIN users ON(post_userid = user_id)
```

that came out like this

```
post_id | post_content   | post_userid | user_id | user_username | user_password | user_name
--------|----------------|-------------|---------|---------------|---------------|----------
1       | Lorem ipsum..  | 1           | 1       | admin         | admin123      | john
2       | Second post .. | 3           | NULL    | NULL          | NULL          | NULL
NULL    | NULL           | NULL        | 3       | test          | test123       | alex
```

Comment: You really tried to format your question. Thank you. But you can use the code button `{}` in the editor to format nicer.

Comment: your select should work. i suspect that post_userid or user_id (or both) are character-fields and one of them contains a whitespace

Comment: Hehe, yea I really tried to explain it, so you guys could understand what I was trying to do ;-)

Comment: I will look after that @BrettSchneider

Comment: Nope, no whitespace @BrettSchneider

Comment: I made a new database and it worked, so something is wrong with my tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = p.post_userid
```

Comment: Well, that was helpfull, but it did not output user 2 (alex)

Comment: Try this:

SELECT * FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON u.user_id = p.post_userid

Will changing the order of JOIN help you?

Comment: If you get only one row, it might be that your user ID do not match in posts table.. I'm blind guessing because I dont have the same DB to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
         post_id,
         post_content,
         post_userid,
         user_id,
         user_username,
         user_password,
         user_name
    FROM posts
    INNER JOIN users ON user_id = post_userid
```

Comment: Please try to run the above query using FULL JOIN and let us know for the results.

Answer (score 0):

since i think your select should work, i suspect character fields for your ids. thus i suggest you try this join:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
 INNER JOIN 
       users 
    ON (rtrim(ltrim(post_userid)) = ltrim(rtrim(user_id)));
```

if that works, you should clean up your ids like this:

```
update posts
set post_userid = ltrim(rtrim(post_userid));

update users
set user_id = ltrim(rtrim(user_id));
```

also you should check whether your application inserts those blanks/whitespaces into your tables and stop it doing so.

Comment: can you send me the ouptut of these selects:
`select CAST(post_userid AS varbinary(max)) from posts;` and `select CAST(user_id AS varbinary(max)) from users;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From posts p
INNER JOIN users u
ON u.user_id = p.post_userid
```